# Flutter: CheckBox doesn't work inside OverlayEntry?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to display some widgets like a CheckBox or a Switch in an OverlayEntry. The overlay is built in a tap event.
The problem is that the bool _value is updated only the first time I tap the CheckBox inside the overlay, but that CheckBox doesn't update its State. The strange thing is that (only the first tap) the tap updates the CheckBox outside the overlay instead of the one inside it.
What I have missed here?

Below a full snippet to reproduce this.

Thanks for your time!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _value = true;

  _buildOverlay() {
    OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
    OverlayState _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);

    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Material(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                child: Checkbox(
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (bool value) { print("$value  $_value"); setState(() => _value = value); },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    _overlayState.insert(_overlayEntry);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {_buildOverlay();},
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Checkbox(
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (bool value) { print("$value  $_value"); setState(() => _value = value); },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In addition to the anmol.majhail solution, using [ValueListenableBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) could be another solution without the need to do a StatefulWidget.

The declaration of `_value` becomes:
`var _value = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);`

and here the _overlayEntry in the _buildOverlay() function:

```
_overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
              valueListenable: _value,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Checkbox(
                    value: _value.value,
                    onChanged: (bool value) { 
                      print("$value  $_value"); 
                      setState(() => _value.value = value); 
                    },
                  );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue here is `Overlay entry` have different context. In Order to make it work you need to separate the `overlay entry` in a separate `stateful` widget - through which you can manage the `checkbox` state.

working Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _value = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    OverlayState _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
                    _overlayState.insert(OverlayEntry(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return OverlayClass(
                          val: _value,
                        );
                      },
                    ));
                    // _buildOverlay(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Checkbox(
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    print("$value  $_value");
                    setState(() => _value = value);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool val;

  OverlayClass({this.val});

  @override
  _OverlayClassState createState() => _OverlayClassState();
}

class _OverlayClassState extends State<OverlayClass> {
  bool _value;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.val;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Material(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Checkbox(
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                print("$value  $_value");
                setState(() => _value = value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```